# How to retrieve less variable using dotless asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, less

I'm using dotless library for compile .less files in my asp.net web-site. And I want to get value of some variable by name.

For example, I have code like this:

```
@FONT_SIZE: 10px;
@TEXT_COLOR: red;
```

So, how can I get font size by "FONT_SIZE" name?
I found FindVariable method in Env class, but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Are you having problems precompiling the .less file or do you just want to know how to use .less variables?

Comment: I want to use following code:

Env env = new Env();
string result = env.FindVariable("FONT_SIZE").Value.ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue using this code:

```
string GetLessVariableByName(string name, string lessContent) {
    int optimisation = 1;
    Func<IStylizer> defaultStylizer = () => new PlainStylizer();
    Func<IImporter> defaultImporter = () => new Importer();
    Func<Parser> defaultParser = () => new Parser(optimisation, defaultStylizer(), defaultImporter());
    Func<Env> defaultEnv = () => { return new Env(); };
    Env env = defaultEnv();
    Parser parser = defaultParser();
    var tree = parser.Parse(lessContent.Trim(), "tmp.less");
    var rule = tree.Rules.ToArray()[0];
    Node node = rule.Evaluate(env);
    var variableValue = tree.Variable(name, node);

    return variableValue == null ? null : variableValue.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your env will be static (needed to read your value). I think you should read your less file as text and use something like a regular expression to get your value.
See: [Import LESS from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128824/import-less-from-server) howto read your less files.
The same problem will be discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dotless/V3SROjkTpM8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would use:

`int optimisation = 1;
            Func<IStylizer> defaultStylizer = () => new PlainStylizer();
            Func<IImporter> defaultImporter = () => new Importer();
            Func<Parser> defaultParser = () => new Parser(optimisation, defaultStylizer(), defaultImporter());
            Func<Env> defaultEnv = () => { return new Env(); };
            Env env = defaultEnv();
            Parser parser = defaultParser();
            var tree = parser.Parse(lessContent.Trim(), "tmp.less");
            var rule = tree.Rules.ToArray()[0];
            Node node = rule.Evaluate(env);`

Question though, where is the ToArray() coming from on the var rule = tree.Rules.ToArray()[0]; line?

Thanks,
Jason